# How to display some HTML by typing it into the address bar?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Is there a way to have the browser display a given HTML page by pasting the HTML code into the address bar and then typing Enter?
Browser is Google Chrome. Unfortunately, if I paste the HTML and then hit enter, it redirects to the Google search site... which is not what I want!

---

I want to paste the HTML code, such as <html><body>...</body></html>

Another option I thought about is to paste something like

javascript:document.write('<html><body>...</body></html>');

but that *appends* the HTML to the current page, while I want to *reset* the page contents instead.

Comment: You will need to be more specific. Do you want only the html or a link like `www.yourdomain.com?html=<html>....</html>`?

Comment: I just edited the question. I do not want to access an external domain, instead I just want the browser to render the HTML.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use `data:text/html,` an example:

```
data:text/html,<h1>Hello World</h1><script>alert('JavaScript works too!');</script>
```

Other examples of data URLs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: Note that if you need to use some more complicated characters (like adding some CSS to change the color of `Hello World`), you'll have to encode them or it won't work. One option is base64: `data:text/html;base64,PGgxIGlkPSJ0aXRsZSI+SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ8L2gxPjxzY3JpcHQ+YWxlcnQoJ0phdmFTY3JpcHQgd29ya3MgdG9vIScpOzwvc2NyaXB0PjxzdHlsZSB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyI+I3RpdGxlIHsgY29sb3I6IHJlZDsgfTwvc3R5bGU+`

Answer (score 7):

```
javascript:document.write("your code here");
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, to make things even easier if you need different HTML displayed at different times, try putting this in the address bar then entering the HTML into the prompt. This JavaScript that goes in the address bar is called a bookmarklet, and if you need to do this often you can add it as a bookmark/favourite for easy access.

```
javascript:document.write(prompt('Enter the HTML', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

URL: `javascript:document.write('foo');`

You can display HTML data using DOM manipulation, but you can't *directly* input HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:void(document.write("<html style='color:red'>HTML goes here</html>"))
```